# How to set table column size in TableRow for Flutter Table

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-table

I have no idea how to set table column size in Flutter. If I use `Row`, `Expanded` can be used, but `TableRow` does not allow it.

Please tell me some advice how to set table column size.
The best solution for me is adjust to size of text length in columns.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can use `defaultColumnWidth` inside `Table` if you want to set same width to each column,

```
Table(
    defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(200.0),
...
```

Output

[image]

---

**Method 2**

you can use a different width for each column.

```
Table(
columnWidths: {
                0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                1: FlexColumnWidth(4),
                2: FlexColumnWidth(4),
              },     
...
```

Output

[image]

Comment: what do for different rowheights?

Comment: The easiest way to think of the column widths is to make them add up to 100. That way you can see each column width as a percentage of the table row width.

Answer (score 25):

For your specific case you can use

```dart
Table(
  defaultColumnWidth: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
  ...
);
```

, since you want the column width to adjust to the text lengths. `IntrinsicColumnWidth` sizes the column based on the width of the content in each cell, ie, the column width increases or shrinks depending upon the length of the content in the cell.

Comment: The width of the table is also reduced to the content.

Answer (score 17):

You can also make two column widths fixed.

```
Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
      columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),// fixed to 100 width
            1: FlexColumnWidth(),
            2: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),//fixed to 100 width
          },
```